Return date as number of seconds in UTC time
I am getting date and time as number of seconds from my table using this T-SQL statement, the date and time is in my current time zone and number of seconds returned is in my current time zone, how can I return number of seconds in UTC time zone instead?
SELECT
    TableName,
    CAST(DATEDIFF(second, '1970-01-01', LastUpdateDate) AS BIGINT) TimestampInSeconds
FROM
    SynchronizationVersions r
WHERE
    LastUpdateDate IS NOT NULL


You probably want to use the AT TIME ZONE built-in statement as it also deals with DST (daylight saving time)

Add the timezone offset in hours to the daterime

Do I understand you correctly: currently both 1970-01-01 and LastUpdateDate are interpreted as being your local timezone (ie the timezone of the machine the SQL server is running on) but you want them both to be interpreted as UTC?

Convert the datetime to datetimeoffset of your timezone and the use at zone 'utc' or whatever the name is. Although I'm not sure if it will correctly account for timezones at the time of the column value. This is one of the reasons people store UTC dates only

It is stored in database in my current time zone, I need to convert them to UTC and return as seconds.

What is the data type of LastUpdateDate? Is it a datetimeoffset? If not, then you don't know what timezone the date represents, so how can you convert it to UTC?

in my country only single time zone also there is no winter/summer time at all, so its in local time zone.

LastUpdateDate column's type is datetime.

Aside... unless you're planning to retire before then and make it someone else's problem, you probably want to be using DATEDIFF_BIG before 2038... db<>fiddle.

Convert your datetime value, to a datetimeoffset with the correct timezone, and then compare to 1970-01-01 in UTC instead:
SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(SECOND, '1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00', LastUpdateDate AT TIME ZONE 'Alaskan Standard Time') --Obviously use your timezone, I just selected a random one
FROM dbo.YourTable;


This seems to work
SELECT
    TableName,
    CAST(DATEDIFF(second, '1970-01-01', 
        LastUpdateDate AT TIME ZONE 'my time zone' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS BIGINT) AS TimestampInSeconds
FROM
    SynchronizationVersions r
WHERE
    LastUpdateDate IS NOT NULL;

